# how to correctly set page layout in itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I'm trying to set continuous page layout, but it doesn't work.

```
Document document = createDocument();
PdfWriter itextWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
itextWriter.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
itextWriter.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageLayoutOneColumn);
document.open();
renderDoc(document);
document.close();
```

What i'm doing wrong?

**UPD** i'm using itext 2.1.7

Answer (score -2):

```
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 120, 80);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        HeaderAndFooter event = new HeaderAndFooter();
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        document.open();
```

in pdf writer
  follow this

```
    byte aonebyte[] = null;
    String exp= null;
    if (aonebyte!= null)
    {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(abyte.length);

        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
        sos.write(abyte);
        sos.flush();
        sos.close();
        exp= null;
    }
    else
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head><title>Error</title></head>\n"
                + "<body><h1>PDF Printer Error</h1><h3>No 'fo' "
                + "request param given.</body></html>");
    }
    return exp;

}
```

Comment: what's this? Why do you show me how to make servlet response? The question is about layouting pages in document. The only thing i found in your answer that _may_ be relevant is `HeaderAndFooter event = new HeaderAndFooter();` but i don't see how. What's more it's not available in version i'm using.